# Typescript support in CSF3

Tags: typescript, storybook

I'm writing Stories using CSF3, and I want to properly annotate my stories. I've Googled and it's basically impossible to find an answer. I've tried some of the techniques [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7677) and nothing quite worked. I found *something* in the storybook website about `Meta` and `ComponentMeta` or `ComponentStory` or something, but I can't find it anymore.

So hopefully someone here can point me to an "easy" actionable answer.

For reference, here's some simple stories where I've tried annotations that don't work.

```
export default { component: DataPresentation } as Meta;

// The simplest version of DataPresentation can simply take DataTable's props plus a tableId
const Default: ComponentStory<typeof DataPresentation> = {
  args: {
    ...DataTableStories.Default.args,
    tableId: "players"
  },
};

const NoFiltering: ComponentStory<typeof DataPresentation> = {
  storyName: 'No search/filter args',
  ...Default,
};
```

- `Default` has an error on `args` which appears to relate to the component props (and might be a "valid" TS error by which I mean a problem with my type relationships and not a storybook quirk)
- There's an error on `NoFiltering` itself (as opposed to on its `args`), which I imagine means I'm simply using the wrong type, and that I don't know what I'm doing, which is the point of asking this question.

> Type '{ decorators?: DecoratorFunction<ReactFramework, Args>[] | undefined; parameters?: Parameters | undefined; args?: Partial<Props> | undefined; ... 6 more ...; story?: Omit<...> | undefined; }' provides no match for the signature '(args: Props, context: StoryContext<ReactFramework, Props>): StoryFnReactReturnType'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no documentation describing how to use CSF3 and especially how to use it with TypeScript.

After some investigation of their source code (storybook version `6.5.9`), I discovered that they have `ComponentStoryObj` type declared for CSF3 format

[image: Storybook source code with multiple story type definitions]

So, to make your code sample work, you need to replace the `ComponentStory` type with the `ComponentStoryObj` type

```js
const Default: ComponentStoryObj<typeof DataPresentation> = {
  // ...
};

const NoFiltering: ComponentStoryObj<typeof DataPresentation> = {
  // ...
};
```

Here is one of the examples I found in their repo - [example](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/d4efb62a70eafbe0590270033a108feb55c78d9d/addons/interactions/src/components/Interaction/Interaction.stories.tsx)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little late, but I also had a bunch of difficulties with this one. The answer by Dzianis Roi did not work for me.

This was what worked for me

```
import { StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';

const Default: StoryObj<typeof DataPresentation> = {
  // ...
};
```

This is the source code that made me realize thats how it works
[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer: the type `ComponentStoryObj` is marked as outdated (or to be deprecated) by storybook, and `StoryObj` should be used instead.