# Storybook component deprecation

Tags: angular, storybook

The setup is Angular 14 and Storybook 6.5.9.

Basically, I have components that I want to test if they are working when consumed by another component. A specific example is a component that exposes Angular Form via VALUE_ACESSOR and I want to create a story that will test if the form is being correctly output to the parent component.

So my component would be like this:

```
export default {
  title: 'Components / Molecule / Multi select dropdown',
  component: MultiSelectDropdownComponent,

  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [
        // all the necessary imports here
      ]
    })
  ],
  argTypes: {
    selectedOptions: { action: 'selectedOptions' },
    selectedFilteredList: { action: 'selectedFilteredList' }
  }
} as Meta;

export const empty: Story<Model.Input> = (props) => ({ props });

export const initial: Story<Model.Input> = (props) => ({ props });
initial.args = Mock.initial; //<-- this is just a file has mocks for all scenarios

export const hasSelectAllConfig: Story<Model.Input> = (props) => ({ props });
hasSelectAllConfig.args = Mock.hasSelectAllConfig;

export const template: Story<Model.Input> = (props) => ({
  props,
  component: MultiSelectDropdownTemplateStoryComponent // <--- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
});
initial.args = Mock.initial;
```

That import of `MultiSelectDropdownTemplateStoryComponent` refers to another file that is an Angular standalone component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'molecule-story-component',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <!-- Here I create the form implementation to "listen" to the actual component -->
    <form [formGroup]="parentForm">
      <molecule-multi-select-dropdown
        [listOptions]="mockData.listOptions"
        [labelName]="mockData.labelName"
        formControlName="form"
      >
      </molecule-multi-select-dropdown>
    </form>
    <button (click)="resetForm()">Reset Form</button>
    <div>Form value: {{ parentForm.value | json }}</div>
  `,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MultiSelectDropdownModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class MultiSelectDropdownTemplateStoryComponent implements OnInit {
  parentForm!: FormGroup;

  mockData = Mock.initial;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._setupForm();
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.parentForm.reset();
  }

  private _setupForm() {
    this.parentForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      form: []
    });
  }
}
```

This strategy helps me verify that my component works, that it works on a parent and is also a guide to new dev members on how to implement this component. Since the implementation is also on the component, my newbie developers ask fewer questions about how to do it, and we can focus more on how it works.

The problem I have is with CSF3. When I mouse over `component`, it says it is deprecated and will be removed on V7. I am planning ahead to check how to make stories like these work since I used to provide not just a template for it, but actually, a different component.

This blog post talks about CSF3: https://storybook.js.org/blog/storybook-csf3-is-here/ but they did not help much to understand how I would refactor my code.

While looking it up, I found [Typescript support in CSF3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549428/typescript-support-in-csf3) which does provide some clarification on things, but then again, the interface `StoryObj<T>` doesn't have a `component` property anymore.

So I am looking for either a solution or a piece of docs that either explain how to do it or confirms that I can no longer provide a whole component and I will need to use some strategy with a `template` only.

Comment: Have you asked in Storybook's GitHub to see what's up with these? I'm late to this breaking-change and got me by surprise too. Probably will need one file per component now?

Comment: I found the PR and asked there https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/21807

Answer (score 0):

With Storybook 7 things changed and it is not possible to define the component like you did. For Rendering Custom Story Components, follow the new approach:

```
export const empty: StoryObj<MultiSelectDropdownTemplateStoryComponent> = {
  render: (args) => {
    return {
      props: args,
      template: `<molecule-story-component></molecule-story-component>`
    };
  }
};
```